# Phonegp App crash using camera

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am exploring the different things that Phonegap can do one of which is taking a photograph and adding it to a page. When I test this however on my device i get as far as taking the picture then the app just crashes with a message on the phone saying "Unfortunately my app has stopped". Here is the code I am using. I'm wondering if its anything to do with the encoding but I did take that directly from the phongap documnet page. #addphoto is a button on the html page that i wish to add the photo to. The photo is to go inside the div with the id noteimage

```
    $("#addphoto").on('click', function(){
         useGetPicture();
    });

      function useGetPicture(){
       var cameraOptions = {
          quality: 75,
          desinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          correctOrientation: true,
      }

      navigator.camera.getPicture( onCameraSuccess, onCameraError, cameraOptions);
   }

function onCameraSuccess(imageData){
    var image = document.getElementById("noteimage");
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onCameraError(message){
    alert("Failed: " + message);
}
```

Comment: You did use the code to request camera permission from the user right?

Comment: Also with what agrothe said, try reducing the image quality once. Say like to 50, and see if it resolved the issue. Also please mention the platform you are using (android/ios etc)

Comment: I have nothing in about permissions. I'm looking for this to work both on ios and android. I'm currently testing on Android. I have reduced the image quality to 50 but still no joy. By the way should i be able to test this in Chrome Ripple

Answer (score 0):

Please check have you given camera permission in manifest file and reduce the quality.

This might be helpful for you...

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageData) {

                    //imageData: base64 string

                  },
                  function(error){
                  alert('error');
                  },
            {quality: 30,targetWidth: 640,targetHeight: 400,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL}
);
```